# Defining minimum score in TextCriteria query with Mongo Spring Data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a dynamic query that depends on a text index as well as other fields. I want to be able to specify a minimum score so that things under the minimum are not getting returned from the query because the text matching is not really close enough to what we are going for to include the results.

I have tried the following but instead of giving me back what I would expect, the query just returns nothing.

```
        Query dynamicQuery = new Query().with(pageable);
        if(includeSearch){
            TextCriteria textCriteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matchingAny(search.trim());
            Criteria minScoreCriteria = Criteria.where("score").gte(2.0);
            dynamicQuery.addCriteria(textCriteria);
            dynamicQuery.addCriteria(minScoreCriteria);
        }

        if(includeSomethingElse){
            Criteria genreCriteria = Criteria.where("somethingelse").in(list);
            dynamicQuery.addCriteria(genreCriteria);
        }

        if(includeAnotherThing){
            Criteria bpmCriteria = Criteria.where("anotherThing").gte(range[0]).lte(range[1]);
            dynamicQuery.addCriteria(bpmCriteria);
        }

        List<MyClass> vos = mongoTemplate.find(dynamicQuery, MyClass.class, "collection_name");
```

Comment: MongoDB Atlas Search would be a much better way to accomplish this effort. That way you would get the Lucene relevance score out the box. It's faster, better, and more language specific.

Answer (score 0):

The text score (`{ $meta: "textScore" }`) can only be used for *projection* and *sort* in regular queries. Therefore the query does not match any documents.
For more details please see: [Text Score Metadata](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/meta/#text-score-metadata-meta-textscore)

Please use an `Aggregation` to filter on *score* as described in the [MongoDB reference documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/).